# Fody.PropertyChanged does not work in F# interactive

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, fody

In my WPF project I have something like this:

```
open PropertyChanged
[<ImplementPropertyChanged>]
type Type1 =
    {   mutable Name : string
        mutable Value : decimal }
```

, and it works fine when compiled and application is running. But in F# interactive I see that "Type1" is not instance of IPropertyChanged. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Why use Fody.PropertyChanged for WPF? FSharp.ViewModule contains everything you need for comfortable using WPF in F#.

Comment: Because Fody.ProertyChanged is considered good practice and is widely used. When I looked at FSharp.ViewModule on github, it seemed stillborn. Maybe I was wrong. Could you show an example of using FSharp.ViewModule?

Comment: http://marisks.net/2015/05/11/f-sharp-xaml-event-driven-mvvm/

Comment: http://stevenpemberton.net/archive/series/FSharpWPF.html